# Installation error R and RStudio RCurl , PKI and other packages

Tags: rstudio, rcpp, rcurl

I have installed a new version of RStudio (ie 0.99 latest release) on Kubuntu14.04. 
When trying to upload a shiny app I get a message which says "Must install RCurl and a couple other packages" - This installation fails with the following:

Installing packages into

```
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘RCurl’
* installing *source* package ‘packrat’ ...
** package ‘packrat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

* installing *source* package ‘PKI’ ...
** package ‘PKI’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

In file included from init.c:1:0:
pki.h:11:25: fatal error:   err.h: No such file or directory
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PKI’
```

---

This was a routine installation, I re-booted to give a clean start, but the same errors occur. 
NB Stack-Overflow wont let me post more than 2 links ( and all the R Compiler messages contain dozens of links ) So there are more messages but these I hope will be sufficient to identify a cure.

Thanks:

Answer (score 6):

You can try to install libssl-dev which the package contains the openssl/err.h file.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

so that you get `curl-config`.   With that my system happily install `PKI` as well.

*Edit:*

```
edd@max:~$ install.r PKI                           ## install.r is from littler
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PKI_0.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 20334 bytes (19 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 19 KB

* installing *source* package ‘PKI’ ...
** package ‘PKI’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs                                           ## I use ccache; rest standard
ccache gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -c asn1.c -o asn1.o
ccache gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -c init.c -o init.o
ccache gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -c pki-x509.c -o pki-x509.o
ccache gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -c tools.c -o tools.o
ccache gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o PKI.so asn1.o init.o pki-x509.o tools.o -lssl -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/PKI/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (PKI)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
edd@max:~$
```